# How to integrate Dialogflow with Django (Python)?

Tags: python, django, machine-learning, webhooks, dialogflow-es

I'm developing an assistant (bot) with Dialogflow, and i have this Django project where I have to extract data and then expose it through the bot, this is going to be stored in a local platform.

I worked with Dialogflow and it's integration before but with Node.js and Javascript, with Django (python) is a brand new challenge and I'm confused.

Until now I have the following:

- I know I can do it with this package: https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-python-client-v2
- I add a url for a webhook, right now this works locally only, like this:

  ```
  from django.http import HttpResponse
  from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
  import dialogflow


  @csrf_exempt
  def webhook(request):
      return HttpResponse('Works like a charm!')
  ```

  and in urls.py I have:

  ```
  url(r'^webhook$', views.webhook, name='webhook')
  ```

And that's all I don't know how to proceed after this, I'm blocked and I don't know how yto make the integration and what's missing, any recommendations?

Answer (score 3):

**Steps**

- Make one html file for your chatbot UI by rendering it with one `url-endpoint` and `view` for displaying purpose of your html file say `bot.html`.
- For dialogflow I first suggest you to build a `dialogflow` `agent` as per you requirement.
- for webhook of `agent` provided by your `djangoserver` which is routed with `localtunnel's` `public IP` (for developement purpose use localtunnel like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to your `django's` `server`)
- then add this link to `fulfillment` of `agent`.

Hey you can refer this [LINK](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-python-client-v2/blob/master/samples/detect_intent_texts.py) using that you just need to

- Create one `url-endpoint` and `view` say `/chatbot`
  which will accepts your text send by bot by `AJAX` request. This `text` is then passes to parameter `texts` in that above functions in link. But make some changes in that functions like without printing `fulfillment text` just return it.
- Then in above `url-endpoint` `/chatbot` return the response as `fulfillmentText` return by that function in link.
- If you wanna use some data of your databases then you can create `django-models` as tables in normal database, for that check the [models - docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/).
  then you can access data by using `models.objects.all()` etc.